# Launch Ogre BaseApplication without Setup dialog

Tags: c++, installation, render, ogre

I'm writing my own Ogre app, based on basic ogre tutorials.

Does anyone know the way to launch OgreRenderWindow without first setup dialog??

I'm aware of [Ogre Basic tutorial 6](http://www.ogre3d.org/tikiwiki/Basic+Tutorial+6&structure=Tutorials), but it doesn't work.

Thanks 4 help

Answer (score 3):

For newer version of Ogre the above solution wont work.

You can do something like the following....

```
  #if defined OIS_LINUX_PLATFORM
  mRoot->loadPlugin("/usr/lib/OGRE/Plugin_ParticleFX");
  mRoot->loadPlugin("/usr/lib/OGRE/Plugin_CgProgramManager");
  mRoot->loadPlugin("/usr/lib/OGRE/Plugin_OctreeSceneManager");
  mRoot->loadPlugin("/usr/lib/OGRE/Plugin_PCZSceneManager");
  mRoot->loadPlugin("/usr/lib/OGRE/Plugin_OctreeZone");
  mRoot->loadPlugin("/usr/lib/OGRE/Plugin_BSPSceneManager");
  mRoot->loadPlugin("/usr/lib/OGRE/RenderSystem_GL");
  #endif

  Ogre::RenderSystemList::const_iterator renderers = mRoot->getAvailableRenderers().begin();

  while(renderers != mRoot->getAvailableRenderers().end())
  {
    Ogre::String rName = (*renderers)->getName();

    if (rName == "OpenGL Rendering Subsystem")
      break;

    renderers++;
  }

  Ogre::RenderSystem *renderSystem = *renderers;
  renderSystem->setConfigOption("Full Screen","No");
  renderSystem->setConfigOption("Video Mode","1024 x 768 @ 32-bit colour");
  renderSystem->setConfigOption("Display Frequency","50 Hz");
  renderSystem->setConfigOption("FSAA","16");
  renderSystem->setConfigOption("Fixed Pipeline Enabled","Yes");
  renderSystem->setConfigOption("RTT Preferred Mode","FBO");
  renderSystem->setConfigOption("VSync","No");
  renderSystem->setConfigOption("sRGB Gamma Conversion","No");

  mRoot->setRenderSystem(renderSystem); 

  // Create a render window
  mWindow =  mRoot->initialise(true, "MyGame v0.0.1");
```

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure, that it is working. Just marked that to thank you. Thanks))

Answer (score 2):

You can find an example of Ogre init without the setup dialog [here](http://www.ogre3d.org/tikiwiki/tiki-index.php?page=MinimalPracticalApplication&structure=Cookbook).

For the Ogre::Root instance you just have to set the render system using `setRenderSystem` and next to that you can set the config options (as in the setup config dialog) using `setConfigOption()`

```
    Root* root = new Root; 
    root->loadPlugin("/usr/local/lib/OGRE/RenderSystem_GL");      
    RenderSystemList *rs = root->getAvailableRenderers(); 
    if(rs&&rs->size()&&rs->at(0)->getName().compare("RenderSystem_GL"))
    { 
             RenderSystem * r=rs->at(0); 
             root->setRenderSystem(r); 

             r->setConfigOption("Full Screen","No");  
             r->setConfigOption("Video Mode","800 x 600 @ 16-bit colour"); 
     }
     else
     { 
             // report error
     }
```